# Move object with hinge joint, but keep it connected to hinge

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have multiple spheres in my mobile game that are attached to hinge joints. The spheres are able to swing and knock into each other, causing other spheres to swing. I am creating movement in the spheres by touching on a sphere and dragging it to a new location. Letting go is supposed to cause the sphere that I just moved to swing accordingly.

The issue is that I am able to move the spheres well outside of the space provided by the hinge. I never want the spheres to move anywhere that they wouldn't be able to swing using the hinge. I am able to move the spheres multiple units/meters away from their original position, when ideally I wouldn't be able to move them more than a few centimeters. The spheres should just stop moving if I hit a limit in the hinge.

Here's my code for the script that controls movement of the spheres:

```c#
GameObject selectedObject;
Vector3 screenPoint;
Vector3 offset;

void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); 
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) // when screen is touched...
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position), Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit)) // ...cast a ray...
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Sphere") //...and check if ray hits a sphere
            {
                selectedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(selectedObject.transform.position);
                offset = selectedObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, screenPoint.z));
            }
        }
    }

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPoint) + offset;
        selectedObject.transform.position = touchPosition;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if I need to explain more or show a video of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a little late but you can use `AddForce()` and `AddTorque()` methods on the object you want to move but that works only if you have `RigidBody` on the object.